# Free groups: normal supplements of the commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, verbal-subgroups

Let $F$ be a free group and let $V$ be another verbal subgroup of $F$ such that
$$
F = [F,F] V.
$$
Is it true that $V=F?$ More generally, if $N$ is a normal (or even characteristic) subgroup of $F$ which also supplements $[F,F],$
$$
F=[F,F] N
$$ 
is it true that $N=F?$

Comment: The question has been [answered](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/213026/commutator-subgroups-as-normal-supplmements) by Keith Kearnes on MathOverflow: if $V$ is a nontrivial verbal subgroup, then $F/V,$ which a _relatively free_ group, has abelian quotients, hence can't be perfect, hence $F=[F,F]V$ is impossible.